# JSR 303 Bean Validation, validation define array values in XML

Tags: java, validation, annotations, bean-validation

I'm trying to create a custom validation wherein I have defined the annotation to accept an array of Strings for example:

```
public @interface Enum {
    String message() default "{}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    String[] value();
}
```

where value is an array of Strings. In the annotation i can use it as @Enum(value={"ABC", "PQR"}) & i can also retrieve this information at runtime. But when i represent the same information in the xml format as.

```
<constraint annotation="com.customvalidation.Enum">
    <element name="value">ABC</element>
    <element name="value">PQR</element>
</constraint>
```

it doesn't work, does any body have idea on how to represent the array in XML..?

Comment: How does it relate to JPA (meaning Java Persistence API)?

Comment: I'm using the Bean Validation(JSR-303) that works with JPA. May be the title is misleading will edit it

Comment: Does anybody have any idea how to implement this? I'm stuck at this point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based only on reading the Hibernate validator [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/reference/en-US/html/validator-xmlconfiguration.html#image-validation-configuration), I think it should be:

```xml
<constraint annotation="com.customvalidation.Enum">
    <element name="value">
         <value>ABC</value>
         <value>PQR</value>
    </element>
</constraint>
```